# Check if connected to app, if not redirect to Login with Facebook PHP SDK / API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm struggling to find a way to detect if users are not connected to my application, I want to send the activity 'View' an 'Item' which works perfectly fine, but they have to click a login link first, when just reloads the page and they are logged in.

How can I make this happen automatically? How can you check if the user is connected to the app?
I have tried the following code, but users who are not connected just get a blank page.

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

    // Check if logged in
    if($user_id) {
            $params = array(
              'ok_session' => 1, // Logged in and connected
              'no_user' => 2, // Logged out of facebook
              'no_session' => 3, // Logged in but not connected
            );
            $next_url = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl($params);

            if($next_url == 2 || $next_url == 3){
                header('Location: '.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream')));
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in
            header('Location: '.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream')));
    }
```

There doesn't seem to be a function that checks if the user is connected so I made use of the `getLoginUrl` function.

`$user_id` is supplied by `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();`

Comment: Just above it is: $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking canvas/page tab app here, then the info you’re looking for is in the `signed_request`parameter your app gets passed on initial load.

If not – “outside” of Facebook the PHP SDK has no way of knowing if there’s a user visiting your page that has used your app before if there aren’t any cookies set for your domain remaining that say so.

You can use `FB.getLoginStatus` out of the JS SDK – that will make a cross-domain request to Facebook to see if the user is logged in, and can set the appropriate cookies under your domain that’ll let the PHP SDK take notice on the *next* request to your server as well.